# Passing generic parameter when passing function as value

Tags: typescript

if I have a generic `function foo<T> : T`, is there some way to specify the type of `T` if passing the function (as opposed to calling it) e.g. `map(foo)`? the function is generic only in its return type, not in any function parameters.

`map(foo<{bar}>)` does not compile.

Comment: No simple way to do this unfortunately, just type assertions

Answer (score 0):

You could express the return type this way: `map(foo as () => {bar})`
Alternate syntax: `map(<() => {bar}>bar)`

Comment: yes, but this could be done for any function, correct? In other words it renders the type parameter useless and in fact bypasses typechecking?

Comment: That's right. But it outcomes to the same as what you wanted to do: stating `foo`'s return type. In both case, that's not exactly bypassing type checking, but setting the type explicitly. It is useful only if your function return type can't be inferred by Typescript (example: the result comes from an external source so its type/structure couldn't be guessed). Are you sure specifying `foo` return type is what you wanted to do? Or maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: thanks @arvymetal but what I want to do is reuse an existing definition that takes a type as generic parameter, as per my original question. I'm trying to leverage the existing generic `foo<>` but I guess I cant do that, per Titian and your replies.

Comment: @shawnT I'm not sure I get it... Assuming you have that function: `const foo = <T>(): T => { return null as T }`, you want to pass it like that: `map(foo<{bar}>)`, which would specify its return type. What I propose does the same: specifying a return type. If you don't specify, the return type will be inferred if possible. I admit that your exemple could be some simplified problem of a more complex case, but I think I lack some information to understand why you need such a syntax. I think it's not possible because the Typescript guys didn't consider it useful.